# loading angular2 on cshtml file

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor, angular

I am trying to load angular2 module in a cshtml file.
I have got the loading working with a html file so I have tried copying all the necessary scripts to cshtml file but it fails to load properly as it fails to load /app/main

This is the original html file tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script>

    System.config({
        packages: {
            'app': {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        },
    });
    System.import('/app/main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div> </div>
</body>

</html>
<pm-app>
    <div>
        <p> Please wait ...</p>
    </div>
</pm-app>
```

And it comes up with the following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

I've tried this with a cshtml with the following code.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script src="~/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script>

    System.config({
        packages: {
            'app': {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        },
    });
    System.import('/app/main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script> 


<h2>Index </h2>

<pm-app>Loading App ...</pm-app>
```

And this comes up with the same error message. I have also tried 
1. putting all the scripts in the header section of the layout page
2. Putting render section in the layout page and adding section in the index.cshtml file.

All three attempts gave me the same error message so I was wondering if this is just purely a bad practice to do it this way ( loading angular module in cshtml ) or if there is any fix to this.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Cheers.

Comment: I'm guessing you have incorrect path in `System.import('/app/main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));`

Comment: Hi Pawel, thanks for your input. I believe the path itself is correct because index.html is in root path. And when I add .js so when it calls  '/app/main.js' , it looks for the next js file which is app.component. So it looks like it's not recognising the js extension config.

Comment: You're missing a `<base>` tag which you'll need later for angular 2 to locate things, I'm also not sure if leaving the main option undefined for the System.config is correct.
Try `packages: { 'app': { main: '/app/main', defaultExtension: 'js' } }` and then `System.import('app')` you might also want a map in your config as the map provides the path hints for the System loader.

Comment: You need to open up your browser's console and actually look at the path it's trying to retrieve from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You just follow this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WA4dPYlRwrE&spfreload=5 
copy your libraries to  _layout.cshtml

Comment: Thanks for your input Phusanakiat. I had a quick look and realised it's for .net core. I will take a closer look and let you know how I go.